# Can we say "just over twice as many as" and "far over twice as many as"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Class 1 has 50 students and Class 2 has 100 students. We say "**Class 2 is twice as many students as class 1**".

Class 1 has 50 students and Class 2 has 95 students. We say "**Class 2 is almost/nearly twice as many students as class 1**".

Class 1 has 50 students and Class 2 has 105 students. Can we say "**Class 2 is just over twice as many students as class 1**" or "**Class 2 is just more than twice as many students as class 1**"?

Class 1 has 50 students and Class 2 has 120 students. Can we say "**Class 2 is far over twice as many students as class 1**"?

Comment: You can certainly say ***just over** twice as many*, but your second alternative is non-idiomatic - should be ***far more than** twice as many* (or ***much** more...*).

Answer (score 1):

*Class X **has**... students...* would be more idiomatic than *class X **is***... students..., I think.
Apart from that, the only one that sounds odd is "far over twice"; you could just use "more than twice as many...".
Twenty percent more doesn't sound like "far over".

Answer (score -1):

> **Can we say** “just over twice as many as”

***Yes we can but we probably would not.***

---

> **Can we say** “***far*** over twice as many as”

I have never heard anyone use this expression; I would use *"more than" or "far more than"*

---

Class 2 **has** twice as many students as class 1".

This sentence is correct but is it how we would normally phrase it? I suggest not.

> **This is what we would probably write.**

"Class 2 has twice, the students of class 1".

"Class 2 has nearly twice, the students of class 1".

"Class 2 has more than twice, the students of class 1".

**This is what most of us (The Masses) would  probably say.**

*"Class 2 has two times more students than class 1"*

> I went to the temple two times today.

> QUOTE; *In informal context, people tend to use two times more than telling twice. That is, **when you speak** with a friend or so, **you use the word two times** rather than twice*. Ref [Twice vs Two times](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-twice-and-vs-two-times/)

Comment: As a British English speaker I would almost never use _two times_ when I meant _twice_!

Comment: @KateBunting No doubt you would, but does everyone else? Quote from learning English; When it comes to twice, this is more often used than two times, although two times is also quite common in informal usage. Compare the following: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv304.shtml

Comment: What @KateBunting said. As [this NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=used+it+two+times%2Cused+it+twice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cused%20it%20two%20times%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cused%20it%20twice%3B%2Cc0) shows ***use it two times*** virtually "flatlines" by comparison with ***used it twice***. I think you're mixing things up with the fact that we nearly always talk about ***using it three times*** rather than ***using it thrice***.

Comment: If you look on the net there are several publications that quite clearly state that for **during informal speech two times is commonly used** Now, just one small question How does NGrams gather it's data for spoken usage? Not written spoken?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Re Thrice, agreed. but If you look on the net there are several publications that state that **during informal speech two times is commonly used** One question How does NGrams gather it's data for spoken usage? Not written spoken? My next comment is not directed at you personally; Now I do tend to reference my answers yet I often receive comments as if they are my words that are wrong whereas in fact  I am quoting sources.  I have received 3 comment in the last few hours where I have been told I am wrong when the item being refuted is  a source that has been referenced? V/Ded?

Comment: Any "publications" saying anything like *during informal speech **two times** is commonly used* aren't to be trusted. I suggest that if anything, the ratio in favour of ***twice*** would be even greater in *speech* than in writing. NGrams *specifically* indexes the entire contents of over 25 million *books*, but obviously at least some of that content will be "reported speech". I'm sure the vast majority of matches for both the two search strings **twice said,two times said** will be reported speech - just feed that into NGrams and note how few matches there are for the second version.

Comment: By the way, I just looked at your "difference between" link. The text there is either generated by a *very* good neural net-powered AI, or by a non-native Anglophone. It's riddled with quirky phrasing and outright errors, and it's certainly not something worth linking to on this site.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Oh! thanks. I just thought it was American. I will edit with a new link later.

Comment: I have stated I do not think NGrams or similar are representative of the use of the spoken word. Now please read and tell me where I am wrong. Two times should be one of the most widely spoken phrases in our language. Along with One times three times , 4x 5x 6x...etc. As it is said every school day in Every English speaking country thousands of times. But on some of these Grams it is not even spoken once a day by one person. **Yes I realise that this is not related to the use of which we are speaking but it should have thrown a major spike for the amount of times two times** is spoken.

Comment: It can therefore be concluded that NGrams and similar are only representative of the written word. Witten works being invariably more formal and mostly written by the more educated members of society. I was also taught to use twice. But many were not.  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171833/twice-vs-two-times